# EC2 with NVMe instance storage - expected performance characteristics?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

What performance characteristics should I expect from an `EC2` instance with NVMe instance storage? 
I've switched to `c5d.large`.
I've created the filesystem. Mounted the device etc.

I'm testing it with hdparm and dd:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-169:/mnt$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:1    0  200G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0  200G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:0    0 46.6G  0 disk /mnt/nvme
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-169:/mnt$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme1n1 

/dev/nvme1n1:
 Timing cached reads:   16624 MB in  2.00 seconds = 8331.98 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 346 MB in  3.05 seconds = 113.55 MB/sec
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-169:/mnt$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/nvme/test bs=1G count=1 oflag=direct
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 25.6933 s, 41.8 MB/s
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-169:/mnt$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-169:/mnt$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-9-169 4.4.0-1063-aws #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 13 07:23:34 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Aren't the values a bit too low for NVMe? 
I've found that the kernel might be not optimized so I've installed the `linux-aws` deb package and restarted.

That didn't improve much, the benchmark results are after the package installation.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing in informal tests between `c5` and `c5d` instances. Random read-write performance is better on the instance storage that comes with `c5d`, but sustained read/writes seems slower than mounted EBS gp2 volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the same question on AWS forum and got a meaningful response.

Turns out that with the smaller instances we don't get the full bandwidth to the NVMe drive.

The bigger the instance the more bandwidth will be at disposal up to the point where multiple NVMe are available above `c5d.9xlarge`).

The **benefit** is that we're getting a reduced latency in all cases.

More details here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=865656

Comment: Of course you don't! The actual NVMe drive will be far larger than 50GB and therefore shared out amongst however many other instances are AWS shoe-horn onto that server - you can't have thought you'd get exclusive access to it can you?